# Rabbit and hare (Wabbit)

Tags: word-request

I hear children call a rabbit **a wabbit**, but what about a hare?

Is there some childish name for it?

Is **wabbit** only used by children?

Comment: "Wabbit" as far as I know, derives from the old Bugs Bunny cartoon. Bugs' nemesis, the hunter Elmer Fudd, has a speech impediment which causes him to pronounce "r" as "w".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most commonly said by Elmer Fudd, a hunter, on the Looney Tunes show, which is an American children's cartoon series. He has a particular speech impediment which causes him to pronounce all his "r"'s as "w"'s. This is often played for laughs because it is usually "Wabbit Season" (Rabbit Season) - the season for hunting rabbits. This causes him to repeatedly bump into Bugs Bunny, who tries increasingly hilarious ways of convincing Elmer that he is not a rabbit or to hunt down his rival, Daffy Duck. It's possible that children may have picked this pronunciation of "rabbit" from watching the show.

[image: Wabbit Season]
[image: Fudd and Bugs]

Answer (score 3):

Unless we are quoting Elmer Fudd, we would not call a rabbit a "wabbit". [Elmer Fudd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elmer_Fudd)

A person with a speech impediment might mispronounce their letter 'r's and some people in certain parts of England soften the 'r' sound and might be misheard as having said a 'w' instead.

The words 'hare' and 'rabbit' are names for different animals, though it is possible for people to be unaware of this and misuse the name. [Difference between hares and rabbits](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2014/12/141219-rabbits-hares-animals-science-mating-courtship/)